# How to display images in a row with IPython display?

Tags: python, ipython

If I execute the following command:

```
for file in files:
    display(Image(filename=os.path.join(folder,file)))
```

I get a list of images in a column:

[image]

How to put them in a row (horizontally)?

Comment: Answers only consider Matplotlib or plain image files. I'd like to do this on Notebook level for assorted elements other than just images. The closest I've gotten is by setting CSS style of .output to `display: grid; grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;` but some elements (such as the SVGs made by plotly) get cropped instead of scaled down.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, imshow, axis
from matplotlib.image import imread

def showImagesHorizontally(list_of_files):
    fig = figure()
    number_of_files = len(list_of_files)
    for i in range(number_of_files):
        a=fig.add_subplot(1,number_of_files,i+1)
        image = imread(list_of_files[i])
        imshow(image,cmap='Greys_r')
        axis('off')
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can also use HTML:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
def make_html(folder, image):
     return '<img src="{}" style="display:inline;margin:1px"/>'
            .format(os.path.join(folder, image))

display(HTML(''.join(make_html(f, x)) for x in files))
```

In my case, by setting a margin will fix the un-alignment (and IMHO produce nicer results).

Comment: Maybe you should add where HTML is coming from. After some googling I think you either refer to this [html module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html) or to [HTML.py](http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html). The former gives me an error when trying to install under python3.6 and the latter is too exotic for me (i.e. not on pipy).

Comment: Ahh, and now I found what you actually were referring to: `from IPython.core.display import HTML`

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution using Jupyter built-in facilities (`IPython.display` and `ipywidgets`):

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import widgets, HBox

imageA = widgets.Image(value=open('path/to/image/a.jpg', 'rb').read())
imageB = widgets.Image(value=open('path/to/image/b.jpg', 'rb').read())

hbox = HBox([imageA, imageB])
display(hbox)

# optional: you can show more hboxes, boxes will be arranged vertically
display(anotherHbox) # 2nd
display(yetAnotherHbox) # 3rd
display(andAnotherHbox) # 4th
```

References:

- Usage of `widgets.Image`: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Image
- `HBox` and layout: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html
- IPython `display`: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display

Be careful that IPython `display` module also has `Image` class, which is different from `widgets.Image` and not compatible with `HBox`.

Comment: this, unfortunately, currently produces extra padding/margin that has white background, instead of transparent.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have to make a figure with subplots, and assign each figure to one of the subplots. Something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,5)
for i in range(5):
    ax[i].imshow(yourimage)
plt.show() # or display.display(plt.gcf()) if you prefer
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an improvement to AkiRoss's answer. This gives more flexiblility on how you display and avoids repeating the function for every row by displaying in a grid format.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def grid_display(list_of_images, list_of_titles=[], no_of_columns=2, figsize=(10,10)):

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    column = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_images)):
        column += 1
        #  check for end of column and create a new figure
        if column == no_of_columns+1:
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
            column = 1
        fig.add_subplot(1, no_of_columns, column)
        plt.imshow(list_of_images[i])
        plt.axis('off')
        if len(list_of_titles) >= len(list_of_images):
            plt.title(list_of_titles[i])
```

Parameters:

- `list_of_images` - a list containing all images you want to display.
- `list_of_titles` - a list containing all titles of image in the same order.
- `no_of_columns` - number of columns in the grid.
- `figsize` - the size of each row to prevent squashing. `(horizontal_size, vertical_size)`.

Example:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("files/tiger_monkey.jpg")
grey_img = cv2.imread("files/tiger_monkey_grey.png")

img_b, img_g, img_r = cv2.split(img)
grey_img_b, grey_img_g, grey_img_r = cv2.split(grey_img)

combi_one = cv2.merge((img_b, grey_img_g, img_r))
combi_two = cv2.merge((grey_img_b, grey_img_g, img_r))
combi_three = cv2.merge((img_b, img_g, grey_img_r))
combi_four = cv2.merge((grey_img_b, img_g, img_r))
combi_five = cv2.merge((grey_img_b, img_g, grey_img_r))
combi_six = cv2.merge((img_b, grey_img_g, grey_img_r))

titles = ["combi_one", 
          "combi_two", 
          "combi_three", 
          "combi_four",
          "combi_five", 
          "combi_six"]
images = [combi_one, 
          combi_two,
          combi_three,
          combi_four,
          combi_five,
          combi_six]

images = [cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) for image in images]   
grid_display(images, titles, 3, (10,10))
```

[image]

Original images:

- [`img`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ1Oz.jpg)
- [`grey_img`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYkgB.png)